# How to get a connection to Amazon S3 using objective c

Tags: objective-c, ipad, connection, amazon-s3

i'm new in accessing Amazon S3 from objective C. I wanna learn some, but then i have problems. I cant get a connection to Amazon S3 because i dont know how to send my username and password using some code. Can somebody tell me how??

Thank you all

Regards,

Risma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amazon has an [AWS SDK for iOS](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/) that allows connecting to S3 via Objective-C. Download the SDK and look at the code examples included with it.

Comment: can you give me a spesific code? i was download it, and try some example, but i did not found, some code for authentification process

Comment: Read the "Getting Started" documentation, it explains explicitly where you put your account credentials: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/5127796662758927